# A basic hello world android app not running

Tags: android

I am using android studio 2.3.3 to develop android apps. Today I created one project. When I configured it with just one activity, i.e mainactivity and tried this app on my real device using USB debugging, it was running.

Then I shared that APK through shareit to my another device of API 26. Then it gave me error: Unfortunately app stopped working.

My app gradle config. is also updated.
i.e

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolVersion 26.0.2
minSdkVersion 21
targetedSdkVersion 26
```

Also, I haven't defined any permission in manifest file.

This app doesn't have any complex code. It is just displaying a textview in mainactivity.

But I have experienced one thing. When I use USB debugging on my API 26 device, and run the app, the app works perfectly.

But if I use signed APK file to run it on API 26, it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the app that is crashing correctly signed?

Comment: try using gradle version 2.2.3 there is some error in 2.3.3.

Comment: what the logcat says about the crash? share the logs.

Comment: Post the logcat pls

Comment: how can i post the logcat? as i already said that the app is running well when i test it... just its crashing when i use .apk file

Answer (score 0):

Your shared APK is build for your device configuration. To share APK you need to build either Using Build APK option or Generate Signed APK option.

To build APK go in Build Option -> Build APK option.

You will get the app-debug.apk inside app->build->outputs->app-debug.apk

Share this APK File to everyone and enjoy.

Comment: your suggestion worked...but before accepting it as an answer. i want to ask...will it work when i create a signed apk?

Comment: i trie it... and i noticed that, when i signed my app using signature version v1 and v2 both.... the app crashes...then i tried using only v2 signature version...still app crashed...theni tried with only version v1 of signature.... then it worked... will you please explain its reason???

Comment: Trace the error when app crash in Android Monitor. Based on that  it will be easy to give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using gradle version 2.2.3 ,in your Project level gradle file, when you want to share application.There is some error in gradle version 2.3.3.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
```

Comment: Why should he use an old version of the gradle plugin?

Comment: I don't know. They introduced Instant run in this Gradle version after that you can only run application for single flavor for android in debug mode. You can define your build variants according to this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: Its a hack that I use whenever I have to share a debug apk, I use 2.3.3 otherwise.